# Install Apache and PHP on Centos without package manager (yum, rpm...)

Tags: centos, php, apache-httpd

Can anyone explain how to Install Apache and PHP on Centos without package manager?
i've only found this documentation in my searches: http://php.net/manual/fr/install.unix.apache.php

Comment: The short answer is "Don't.  Just install the package".  This answer is especially appropriate *if you have to ask* how to install a program without using a package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you begin your compilation you should need additional header files and libraries required, please use the following code to install pre-requisities, don’t delete them as you would definitely need them when you upgrade to new releases also :

```
yum install make gcc automake zlib-devel bison cmake libtool wget gcc-c++ unzip ncurses-devel openssl-devel pcre-devel libxml2-devel curl-devel gd-devel libxslt-devel
```

**Building & Installing Apache :**

```
wget http://ftp.itu.edu.tr/Mirror/Apache//httpd/httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz
tar zxvf httpd-2.2.25.tar.gz 
cd httpd-2.2.25
```

Normally below options are widely used :

```
./configure \
        "--prefix=/etc/httpd" \
        "--exec-prefix=/etc/httpd" \
        "--bindir=/usr/bin" \
        "--sbindir=/usr/sbin" \
        "--sysconfdir=/etc/httpd/conf" \
        "--enable-so" \
        "--enable-dav" \
        "--enable-dav-fs" \
        "--enable-dav-lock" \
        "--enable-suexec" \
        "--enable-deflate" \
        "--enable-unique-id" \
        "--enable-mods-static=most" \
        "--enable-reqtimeout" \
        "--with-mpm=prefork" \
        "--with-suexec-caller=apache" \
        "--with-suexec-docroot=/" \
        "--with-suexec-gidmin=100" \
        "--with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suexec_log" \
        "--with-suexec-uidmin=100" \
        "--with-suexec-userdir=public_html" \
        "--with-suexec-bin=/usr/sbin/suexec" \
        "--with-included-apr" \
        "--with-pcre=/usr" \
        "--includedir=/usr/include/apache" \
        "--libexecdir=/usr/lib/apache" \
        "--datadir=/var/www" \
        "--localstatedir=/var" \
        "--enable-logio" \
        "--enable-ssl" \
        "--enable-rewrite" \
        "--enable-proxy" \
        "--enable-expires" \
        "--with-ssl=/usr" \
        "--enable-headers"
```

to build and install source distro, type :

```
make
make install
```

**Building PHP from the source :**

```
wget http://us2.php.net/get/php-5.5.5.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
tar zxvf php-5.5.5.tar.gz
cd php-5.5.5
./configure \
        --with-apxs2 \
        --with-curl=/usr \
        --with-gd \
        --with-gettext \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
        --with-kerberos \
        --with-openssl \
        --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/lib \
        --with-mhash \
        --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
        --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
        --with-pcre-regex \
        --with-pear \
        --with-png-dir=/usr \
        --with-xsl \
        --with-zlib \
        --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
        --with-iconv \
        --enable-bcmath \
        --enable-calendar \
        --enable-exif \
        --enable-ftp \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --enable-soap \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --enable-zip \
        --enable-wddx
make
make install
libtool --finish /root/php-5.5.5/libs
cp php.ini-production /usr/local/lib/php.ini
sed -i 's/;date.timezone =.*/  date.timezone \= "Asia\/Calcutta"/' /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what i was looking for. :)